# Create ImageMagick Linux script

Tags: linux, imagemagick

I have an imagemagick convert command that I use from the shell and I would like to create a linux exec to run it, so I don't have to always run this.

I am converting a PDF file to JPEG files, and this is what I use:
convert -density 300 *.pdf  -alpha off -scale 1500x2000 -quality 70 jpegFiles.jpg

What I would like the linux exec file to do is run the above convert and instead of jpegFiles, to have the actual PDF filename. Of course, for every page jpeg file it would have  filename-0.jpg, filename-1.jpg, filename-2.jpg, etc.

I am using Ubuntu.
Thank you.

Comment: why is C++ a tag here ? Do you need this to be in C++ ? What does _exec file_ mean ? Do you mean a script - which I think is appropriate ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

save this in a file and place it in a dir like *`$HOME/.bin`*
eg. *`$HOME/.bin/pdf2jpg`*

```
for file in "$@"; do
    convert -density 300 "$file" -alpha off -scale 1500x2000 -quality 70 "${file%.*}-%d.jpg"
done
```

make it executable

```
chmod +x $HOME/.bin/pdf2jpg
```

and add that dir to the PATH variable

```
echo "PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.bin" >> $HOME/.bash_profile    # assuming you use bash
```

---

create a dir named as your pdf along with *-images* suffix and place the files in there

```
for file in "$@"; do
    dir="${file%.*}-images"
    mkdir -p "$dir"
    convert -density 300 "$file" -alpha off -scale 1500x2000 -quality 70 "$dir/${file%.*}-%d.jpg"
done
```

Comment: Works great, thank you. Is there a way to also create a dir (with the name of the file) and place the files in that?

Comment: yep, see my edited answer, just change the output files' path